# Why cant I use <br> between <textarea> and <table>?

Tags: html, line-breaks

I've a JSF XHTML template which generates the following HTML. I need to separate the `<textarea>` and the `<table>` with a `<br>`, but when I write it nothing happens.

```
<br />
<span>Historial de Actividades</span>
<br />
<br />
Contenido
<br />
<textarea></textarea>
<br />
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button><span>Guardar</span></button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I just don't understand why I can use `<br>` in lines 1, 3 & 4 and not in line 8. Just need a simple "line break" there!

I noticed that if I put the code inside other `<table>`, it does what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you want? The `<h:panelGrid>` generates a HTML `<table>` which all by itself already starts in a new line. I'm absolutely not seeing how a `<br>` is useful here. Does it otherwise still stick on the right side of the text area? That's not the default behavior. Something in CSS is then causing this, likely a wrong float. You'd need to show HTML+CSS in MCVE flavor in order to get it solved by us. Or, do you actually want some extra more margin on top of the table? If so, why not just using CSS `margin` for that instead of a silly `<br>`?

Comment: @BalusC I actually wanted two `<br/>` between  the `<p:inputTextarea>` and the `<h:panelGrid>`. One of them is generated by the `<h:panelGrid>` as you said, but the other one is just being ignored. I want to know why it is ignored. There is no problem with CSS the others <br/> work. I did this for simplicity as I did after the first `<h:outputText>`.

Comment: You've basically a HTML question. JSF is in the context of this question merely a HTML code generator. You'd better reframe the question and target on `[html]` audience instead of `[jsf]` and post some pure HTML snippet instead of a piece of JSF markup which no one non-JSF-aware HTML user would ever understand. Once done that, you'll have better chances on the HTML question being answered by a HTML expert who will tell something about inline and block level elements. Once having the answer, just alter JSF code accodingly that it generates exactly the desired HTML (and CSS).

Comment: I tried that but I´m using forward. Give me time to make that change...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you can't use the `<br/>`, but you can use a `p:spacer`:

```
<p:spacer height="20" width="100%" />
```

Or if you want a horisontal line:

```
<p:separator />
```

You could also do it with a `styleClass`, or wrap the elements in `p:outputPanel`.